# Type mismatch: cannot convert from void to int for session.setPortForwardingL();

Tags: java, ssh

int assinged_port=session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);

Comment: it's saying that `session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);` is a void method, which returns nothing and cannot be assigned to an `int`

Comment: I'm trying some code,Follow this link  https://www.journaldev.com/235/java-mysql-ssh-jsch-jdbc

Comment: @shashisharma What version of jsch are you using?

Answer (score 0):

setPortForwardingL does not return a value. It's signature is "public void setPortF..." You can't assign "nothing" to a variable.

Also, "void" is not the same as "null".

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/235/java-mysql-ssh-jsch-jdbc    Please check this link

Answer (score 0):

it's saying that `session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);` is a void method, which returns nothing and cannot be assigned to an `int`